# Returning recursive result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I currently have this in a simple MVC Api controller:

```
var rootFolder = Umbraco.TypedMedia(200);

                return rootFolder.Children().Select(s => new MediaItem
                {
                    Name = s.Name,
                    Children = s.Children.Select(e => new MediaItem
                    {
                        Name = e.Name
                    })
                 });
```

It works, but only return level 1 and 2.

I tried using

`return rootFolder.Descendants()`, which returns all results from all levels - but "flattened out", so I cannot see the structure in the output.
The output is used in a simple app, navigating a tree structure.

Any ideas, as to how I can make it recursive?

Using Descendants, the output is returned like this

```
[
    {
        "Name":"dok1"
    },
    {
        "Name":"dok2"
    },
    {
        "Name":"dok21"
    }
]
```

But it should be

```
[
    {
        "Name":"dok1"
    },
    {
        "Name":"dok2"
        "Children": [
        {
            "Name":"dok21"
        }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: How would you like the output structured? Could you add an example of what you want the "return" to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you really *need* recursion here -- the solution below (or something similar) should suffice

```
// Dictionary between level/depth(int) and the files on that level/depth
var fileDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<MediaItem>>();
var children = rootFolder.Children();
var depth = 1;
while (children.Any())
{
    var tempList = new List<MediaItem>();
    children.ForEach(child => {
        tempList.Add(child);
    });
    fileDictionary.Add(depth, tempList);
    children = children.Children();
    depth++;
}
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
foreach (var key in fileDictionary.Keys)
{
   // Access the key by key.Key (key would be "depth")
   // Access the values by fileDictionary[key] (values would be list of MediaItem)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a recursive function like so?

```
IEnumerable<MediaItem> ConvertToMediaItems(IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> items)
{
    return items?.Select(i => new MediaItem
    {
        Name = i.Name,
        Children = ConvertToMediaItems(i.Children)
    }) ?? Enumerable.Empty<MediaItem>();
}
```

Then the usage would be

```
var rootFolder = Umbraco.TypedMedia(200);

return ConvertToMediaItems(rootFolder.Children());
```

You can also make the function a local function if it's only needed in one place.